# How to make BBEdit use Homebrew shellcheck?

Tags: homebrew, bbedit

On my Air I have `shellcheck` installed via Homebrew (`/opt/homebrew/bin/shellcheck`) and my BBEdit installation is aware of it - when editing a file detected as "Unix Shell Script" the **#! -> Check Syntax** menu option is enabled.

On my new Mini, I also have `shellcheck` installed but BBEdit never enables the menu.

I've checked various things on the Air:

- Command history for any `defaults write` ❌
- Symlinks to make `shellcheck` available via another path ❌
- Settings within BBEdit ❌
- BBEdits [Expert Preferences documentation](https://www.barebones.com/support/bbedit/ExpertPreferences.html) ❌

On the Mini, I have quit and restarted BBEdit and rebooted the machine, to no effect.

What am I missing to enable BBEdit to see/use `shellcheck`?

### Update

Following a suggestion from Barebones support, I have run the command below via BBEdit's "Text ➝ Run Unix Command" menu item:

```
printenv; which -a shellcheck
```

That reveals that BBEdit is seeing a `$PATH` which includes `/opt/homebrew/bin` and that it *can* see `shellcheck` as `/opt/homebrew/bin/shellcheck`

Sadly the "Check syntax" menu item is still not being enabled.

Comment: Did you reach out to BBEdit already about this? What was their response?

Comment: I have now, and they've pointed me towards https://www.barebones.com/support/bbedit/zshenv.html which looks promising

Comment: If you figure it out, feel free to self-answer.

Comment: That's 100% the intention - I've just got some .zshrc / .zprofile stuff to work through first...